# Which auxiliary should I use in this question tag?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, question-tags

> Children sleep with a smile. Funny,_____?

I need a question tag. Which one is it: *isn't it* or *aren't they* or *don't they*?

Comment: You're confusing the context by ending the first sentence and starting a new one with ***Funny***, which clearly implies a "deleted" preceding element. But we can't say with any certainty what that preceding text might have been. If it was ***They (the children) are** funny* the tag would be ***aren't they?*** But it might be ***It (the preceding statement) is** funny*, in which case the tag would be ***isn't it?*** And if it was contracted from ***They sleep in a funny way*** it would be ***don't they?***.

Comment: Your first question was migrated to English Language Learners and is there any reason to post a similar question here?

Comment: "Be" + 3rd person pronoun can occur as tag to a verbless anchor. Nothing unusual about "Lovely day, isn't it?"; "Beautiful ship, isn't she?" The only choices in your example are "isn't it?" (the fact that they sleep with a smile) or "aren't they?" (the way they do things); either would be grammatically okay.

Answer (score 3):

If you're focusing on the funny thing being that children sleep with a smile, you'd use **isn't it?**. The sentence including the omitted pronoun would be

> Children sleep with a smile. It's (or that's) funny, isn't it?

If you're focusing on children themselves being funny for doing that, you'd use **aren't they?**. There, the pronoun-included sentence would be

> Children sleep with a smile. They're funny, aren't they?

There is no situation here where **don't they?** would be correct; funny isn't a verb. (As FumbleFingers pointed out in his comment, you'd have to make the follow-on sentence "They sleep (in a) funny (way), don't they?" for this to work.)

Answer (score 1):

Question tag is made of `auxiliary verb` and a `pronoun` of the sentence.

Accordingly, options `isn't it?`, `aren't they?` are clearly ruled out for the following sentence,

> Children sleep with a smile. Funny,_____?

and the other option `Don't they?` is used if the sentence is

> Children sleep with a smile, don't they?`

Since your focus is on 
**funny**, the question tag for the following sentence is **isn't it?**

> Children sleep with a smile.**(It is)** Funny,isn't it?

---

Comment: There seems to be something worthwhile in this answer, but the formatting spoils it. Can you clean up the layout a bit? Maybe introduce some paragraph breaks, and definitely fix the broken markup in the final sentence.

Comment: Are you saying that 'Children sleep with a smile. Funny, isn't it?' is unacceptable, or merely an acceptable construction that should not be labelled a 'question tag'?  If the latter, your second sentence needs clarifying. // I'd argue that the undeleted form 'It is funny, isn't it?' makes 'isn't it' a question tag in any case. In any case, terminology aside, OP is asking whether 'isn't it?', 'aren't they?' or 'don't they?' may / should be used.

Comment: I meant 'isn't it?' is the acceptable tag for the sentence..guess it is due to poor formatting,this argument arose. will focus on presentation to avoid confusion @EdwinAshworth